# How to make a child view determine parent/sibling view size with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two `UIView`s stacked vertically, and a parent-view enclosing them like this:

[image]

View B is a horizontal stack view, I may add child-views to it dynamically with code. What I want is:

1. When View B width changes, the parent view width changes with it.
2. View A width changes with the parent, and redraw itself to fit the new size.

I added the constraints for View A and View B for their leading and trailing to be the same as  the parent view. I thought when View B grows, it will 'push' the parent view to be as wide as itself, and the parent view will 'stretch' View A to the same width.

But it turns out since View A has its initial width, the parent view width is limited by that, and View B width is limited by the same width. View B doesn't grow, but gets squeezed instead.

How do I make View B determine the width of other views? I hope to use constraints, not setting frames each time view size changes.

Comment: You need view A _not_ to have an "initial width" if you want view B to dictate the width of the parent and of view A.

Comment: @matt What if I need View A or the parent view to have an initial width? (In my case, it is the width of the screen). I guess my question is: how to specify which view dictates when constraints among multiple views are involved?

Comment: @NeoWang did you try settings parent view width after adding child to View B? You can define width constraint to parent view and after addition of children views you can get View B frame width and set it to parent width constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the size change, simply change the width of view A to be greater than or equal to. That way it can be that size or greater. In the same size inspector, there is a "Content Compression Resistance Priority". Higher numbers make the view less likely to shrink. If you change your resistance to 1000 on view B, it will be less likely to resize improperly.

[image: Xcode greater than or equal view size][image: Xcode content compression resistance priority]